# Is there any better way to use transliteration function in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, text-editor, ace-editor

I am working on project where i need transliteration support in ace editor

Currently my code look like this

```js
editor.container.addEventListener("keydown", (key) => {
  if (toggleBtn.checked) {
    if (key.code == "Space" || key.code == "Enter") {
      let pos = session.selection.getCursor();
      let text = session.doc.$lines[pos.row]
        .slice(0, pos.column)
        .split(" ")
        .pop();
      let transliteratedStr = transliteratorFuction(text); //this is return Eng to Sanskrit transliteration
      editor.session.replace(
        {
          start: {
            row: pos.row,
            column: pos.column - text.length,
          },
          end: pos,
        },
        transliteratedStr
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any better way to do it.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are there any particular problems with this method that you'd like to fix? As far as i can tell there can be made few small tweaks, like to make this work with multiple cursors, but overall your method should be good enough.

Comment: I want to make it like Google input means whenever user will start typing it will start transliteration once done (on sapce/line break) it will stop and wait for new word

Comment: Not sure which google input do you mean. Maybe you could update your question with more detailed description of behavior, or a screenshot or a link to a page where this happens.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wwODzmWHX8s see this